# How do I execute an if statement inside an image_tag helper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Basically what I want to do is check to see if a method returns true on an object, if it does, then apply a specific class to the image.

If not, then do nothing.

So I tried this:

```
<%= image_tag(upload.image.url, if upload.upvoted? :class => 'upvoted') %>
```

But this is the error I get:

```
/app/views/stages/compare.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...d.upvoted? :class => 'upvoted') );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
/app/views/stages/compare.html.erb:31: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
');              end                        
                    ^
/app/views/stages/compare.html.erb:63: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/app/views/stages/compare.html.erb:65: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Comment: I didn't actually try this so I may be wrong, but in your initial code the if statement doesn't seem to be valid. Maybe you could try this:  <%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => 'upvoted' if upload.upvoted? ) %>

Comment: Victor, look at the answers. They are spot on. I just chose bensie's answer because it works like a charm. Although, beerlington's own is pretty good for my updated needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => upload.upvoted? ? 'upvoted' : nil) %>
```

Comment: bensie this is awesome. One more twist, say I wanted to do two checks in one. Say I wanted to do the following workflow: if `upload.upvoted?` apply class 'upvoted'. However, if `upload.downvoted?` apply class `downvoted`. If neither, do nothing. Is it possible for me to do that as succinctly as you have done here ?

Comment: Define a cssclass variable above to do your checking and use :class => cssclass to set it.

Comment: Why not just create a helper, pass it the upload variable, and have it return the right class?

Comment: @beerlington - that works too.  original question seemed simple enough to not need an external helper...

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, I would move the logic for determining the class to a helper method:

```
module StageHelper
  def upload_class(upload)
    if upload.upvoted?
      'upvoted'
    elsif upload.downvoted?
      'downvoted'
    end
  end
end
```

Then your image tag help would be:

```
<%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => upload_class(upload) %>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Do I generate a helper with `rails generate helper Stage` at the command line ?

Comment: You can just create it in app/helpers

Comment: I am getting this error: `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` around this line: `<div class="image-wrapper"><%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => upload.class(upload)) %></div>`

Comment: Should be upload_class, not upload.class (assuming that's your helper method name)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the full block of code this line appears in: https://gist.github.com/880330

Comment: Brilliant! That `_` is what was causing it. Thanks man. Ok, to be fair...I really should give the answer to this problem to bensie, because he answered what I asked. So what I am going to do is  just ask another question more tailored to your answer and you just copy and paste this there and I will mark that as answered, ok ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384369/how-do-i-apply-one-of-two-classes-to-an-image-depending-on-a-certain-condition-in   That's the question. Post your response here and I will mark it accepted. Thanks again