# How do I apply one of two classes to an image depending on a certain condition in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So for one class, I would do something like:

```
<%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => upload.upvoted? ? 'upvoted' : nil) %>
```

But I want to have it check to see if `downvoted` applies, and if so applies the class `downvoted'. If it doesn't apply, it checks to see if`upvoted` does, and then applies that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the logic for determining the class to a helper method:

apps/helpers/stage_helper.rb

```
module StageHelper
  def upload_class(upload)
    if upload.upvoted?
      'upvoted'
    elsif upload.downvoted?
      'downvoted'
    end
  end
end
```

Then your image tag help would be:

```
<%= image_tag(upload.image.url, :class => upload_class(upload) %>
```